# Python regex group() works, but findall() results are not as I expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing some logs and want to extract all parameter names of a certain type. For simplicity, I'll just include a small substring.

```
log = 'WT.tz=-8&WT.bh=23&WT.ul=en-US'

#I want to find all strings that start with WT and get WT and all the following characters until I find an & or the end of the string. I tested this on an online regex page and it seems to work great.
regex = r'(?s)(?=WT).+?(?=(=))'

# if I try to find the first I get what I expected
re.search(regex,log).group()
>> 'WT.tz'

#when I try to find all I do not get what I thought I was going to get.
re.findall(regex,log)
>> ['=','=','=']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findall returns all the `groups`.You have a group `(=)`.So remove it.

```
regex = r'(?s)WT.+?(?==)'

                   ^^^^^
```

Also there is no need for `lookahead`.

Output: `['WT.tz', 'WT.bh', 'WT.ul']`

Answer (score 0):

```
log = 'WT.tz=-8&WT.bh=23&WT.ul=en-US'

print(re.findall(r'WT\.[^&]*\b',log))

['WT.tz=-8', 'WT.bh=23', 'WT.ul=en-US']
```